# Where is Jasmeet born, in London or India?

Tags: plot-explanation, namastey-london

In movie Namaste London, after meeting Bobby Bedi, Jasmeet says to her friend that she doesn't want to marry an Indian groom as she is British as she has born in London.
However, when she visits India with her family, there's an old lady called Bebe (common word for grandmother) by everyone that  Manmohan left India, when Jasmeet was too young babe. She says something like:

> Itni si thi

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namastey_London) also states the same in the synopsis that Jasmeet was born after moving to London.

So, why does no one correct Bebe, that she never visited India before, as everyone is there like Jasmeet's father Manmohan Malhotra, his wife and other people from BeBe's family?

Comment: I don't have any personal knowledge of this film... but I though Indians were very respectful of their elders... perhaps no one wanted to correct her.

Comment: That may be possible, however there is not context to show somethings. I firstly thought it may be by mistake, directors missed . However, I am not finding it in IMDB or any site as mistake

Comment: movies aren't fault proof. but could be the case that they've visited India before when Jasmeet was little. It's not possible to show every single history.

Comment: Looks like a plot inconsistency.